# How will Smart Contracts be implemented on the Tangle, providing timestamps are enforced?

Tags: tangle, dag, smart-contract

On the main DAG? On a second layer? Or something else?

How does it work basically?

Answer (score 2):

In IOTA timestamp accuracy cannot be trusted.

> "The tangle is a graph with only a partial order structure, which
>   makes it difficult (in fact, generally impossible) to establish the
>   correct time order of transactions. Even if all transactions have
>   timestamps on them, we cannot be sure that all these timestamps are
>   accurate"

Source: http://iota.org/timestamps.pdf

[image: Tangle vs Blockchain]

In blockchain all blocks are organised into a linear sequence over time so this problem does not persist.

To make Smart Contracts on the Tangle possible, an "off-tangle" [oracle](https://blockchainhub.net/blockchain-oracles/) will be implemented.

IOTA Foundation is actively working on [Oracle platform for IOTA](https://blog.iota.org/a-primer-on-iota-with-presentation-e0a6eb2cc621#b9e6) where the plan is also to enable true interoperability with all other Blockchain platforms.

Comment: So the main DAG will be left untouched, and a second layer of the Oracle platform will be implemented? Then Smart Contracts and Interoperability will be enabled on this second layer, am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Yes. That's a different layer.

Answer (score 2):

Ales has his own take, but I think he is perhaps ruling out smart contracts based on perceived functionality from other implementations.

http://iota.org/timestamps.pdf

> Even if all transactions have timestamps on them, we cannot be sure that all these
>   timestamps are accurate (there can be some malicious nodes that want to fool the
>   network about the true time when their transactions appear, and/or some nodes
>   with a wrong clock). Nevertheless, one can determine the confidence intervals for
>   timestamps with reasonable accuracy

Timestamps per say are not important to implementing smart contracts. What is necessary, is a proper ordering of when transactions were completed. Something that datetimes are very good at, but it can be accomplished in other ways.

If that confidence interval approaches 100%, you can create logic that depends on that order.

Hell, we can't even be sure that a Transaction was even confirmed or not with a 100% confidence interval.

In order for IOTA to be successful, we need to be comfortable with the confidence intervals and probability distributions.

Comment: Judging from the link Ales provided, it seems clear to me that Smart Contracts will be implemented on a second layer - an Oracle platform, on top of the Tangle's base protocol.

But are you proposing a solution to directly implement Smart Contracts on the Tangle?

Comment: Yes, precisely. The way the whitepaper about timestamps is written, it makes it sound like "yea, they don't work the way everybody is used to them working but it is possible".

In a similar way that Michelin tires can "guarantee" that your tire will last for for $50,000 miles we can identify the confidence interval of a timestamp.

99% 99.9%, 99.99% or 99.9999% 

How many decimals is acceptable? Is it reasonable to achieve such confidence intervals? Those are the next questions to answer.

I view the Oracle second layer approach as a fall back plan.